# Creating dynamically loaded Linux libraries using Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse

I am writing a program in C++ using Eclipse. I want to compile it as a library for Linux, somthing like a DLL in Windows. How I can do this? Do you know any tutorials on how libraries are created?

I just want to understand that is the analog of a DLL for Linux and how to create it. I will be thankful for a small example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Linux, DLL's equivalents are (kind of anyway) shared objects (.so).

You need to do something like this:

```
$ g++ -c -fPIC libfile1.cpp
$ g++ -c -fPIC libfile2.cpp
$ g++ -shared -o libyourlib.so libfile1.o libfile2.o
```

Take a look at some open source C++ library projects for more information. [GTKMM](http://www.gtkmm.org/) is one of them.

Of course, instead of compiling everything manually it's highly recommended to use a **make file** or an **IDE** (such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) or [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) or {*pick your favorite here*}) that will create one for you behind the scenes.

Comment: You should add the -fpic or -fPIC option to the "g++ -c ..." calls. This is to generate "position independent code" so Linux can share the same code in memory between several processes.

Answer (score 6):

In UNIX/Linux world DLLs are called `shared libraries` and typically have `.so` or `.o` extension.

See Linux [HOWTO](http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) on shared libs.

Comment: .a are not shared, but static libraries

Comment: ,o files are not shared libraries - they are object files

Comment: AIX used ".o" for both object files and shared libs. At least it was so in AIX 4.x, don't remember about 5.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the default visibility of symbols. It can improve performance. Check out the [GCC wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) entry on the subject.

There is also a [paper](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) written by Ulrich Drepper in 2006 that describes the proper way to implement dynamic shared objects on UNIX systems.